# Unexpected Character When sending SOAP request from Linux

Tags: xml, curl, soap

I was trying to send a SOAP request.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "SOAPAction: " --data-binary file.xml  https://endpoint.com
```

I specified the request body in xml file as -

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dse="http://brandmaker.com/webservices/dse/v2/">
 <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <dse:findById>
      <id>1405</id>
    </dse:findById>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This file works fine when I sent the request from Mac. However, when I copied the file from Mac to Linux and tried the same command, I encountered invalid character issue -

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body> . 
     <soap:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Error reading XMLStreamReader: Unexpected character 'f' (code 102) in prolog; expected '&lt;' at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]</faultstring>
     </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>%
```

I tried escaping the content, still I am getting the same error -

```
&lt;soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/&quot; xmlns:dse=&quot;http://brandmaker.com/webservices/dse/v2/&quot;&gt;
   &lt;soapenv:Header/&gt;
   &lt;soapenv:Body&gt;
     &lt;dse:findById&gt;
       &lt;id&gt;1405&lt;/id&gt;
     &lt;/dse:findById&gt;
   &lt;/soapenv:Body&gt;
&lt;/soapenv:Envelope&gt;
```

Can anyone help me? How should I encode the xml request body when sending request from Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it is sending POST data that contains the literal text `file.xml`.

Try:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: text/xml" \
-H "SOAPAction: " \
--data-binary @file.xml \
https://endpoint.com
```

For Linux, the documentation for `--data-binary` reads:

```
--data-binary <data>
    (HTTP) This posts data exactly as specified with no extra processing whatsoever.

    If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a filename.
    Data is posted in a similar manner as --data-ascii does, except  that  newlines
    and carriage returns are preserved and conversions are never done.

    If this option is used several times, the ones following the first will
    append data as described in -d, --data.
```